# Jetpack Compose Room Database Flow, deleting item from database causes recompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

No code, just a theoretical question.

The scenario is this
Room database with one table which houses the fields necessary.
Flow is setup to watch for database changes and report back to the UI.

So. sitting on page

/user/5

There is a delete button. Click the delete button the event passes up to the viewmodel and the viewmodel reacts.

## UIDisplayUserDetails.kt

```
@composable
Button {
onclick: 
  event -> deleteClicked
  navigation("userlist")
```

==================

## viewmodel.kt

```
event deleteclicked {
  repository.deleteUser(5)
}
```

=================

The design flaw is as follows.
The user deleted from the Room database works great. But that change in the Room database causes the Flow to recognize a change in the table in the Room database. That in turn sends the changes down stream. Which in turn causes a recompose.
The recompose causes a recompose on /user/5 which no longer exists in the database. Then things break.

What would be the correct method to delete a record from the Room database without causing a recompose. or the correct way to think about how to do this.

thanks

Tried to delete a record from the Room database, which works, but that causes a recompose. I either don't want the recompose, or want a new way to think about this design pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set things up like below then it should recompose UsersRow() from the state of `users` changing which would then leave out user 5 entirely when it is deleted from Room. This would avoid a crash I beleve.

```
@Composable
fun UsersRow(context: Context, viewModel: UserViewModel) {
    val users by viewModel.getUsers().observeAsState()   // Observing livedata/flow

    Row {
        users.forEach { user ->
            UserCard(user)
        }
    }
}
```

[List docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists)

[State and Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)